# Create a generic function that return a generic type list in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have two `Model` classes, one is `Person` and the other is `Department`. What I want to achieve is I want to create a generic function which can be used to retrieve generic type data in the form of `List` for e.g. one call will return `Person List` , another call will return `Department List`. More specifically I want to return data in the form of a List.

The below is the `Person` Class.

```
public class Person {

    public Int16 Personid{ get; set; }
    public string Personname { get; set; }
    public string Personaddress { get; set; }

}
```

The below is the `Department` class.

```
public class Department {

     public Int16 Departmentid { get; set; }
     public string Departmentname { get; set; }
     public string Departmentsection { get; set; }

}
```

The below are the calling function where One time I make a call with `CallingMethodPerson()` and other with `CallingMethodDepartment()`.

```
public class CallingClass {

   public void CallingMethodPerson() {

      CalledClass calling = new CalledClass();
      Calling. CalledMethod();

   }

    public void CallingMethodDepartment() {

      CalledClass calling = new CalledClass();
      Calling. CalledMethod();

    }
}
```

The below blue print is the `CalledClass` where it does some manipulation and return List of either `Person` or `Department`.

```
public class CalledClass {

    public void CalledMethod() {
      //this is a generic method wherein returns the list of either a Person 
      or Department whenever called.

    }
}
```

To summarise I want to implement a common function that return generic type data. The trick is actually I want build one generic function that has a `SQL Read command`, so I will call the same function again and again with different models, execute the query, retrieve the data from the `database`, store it into a `list` of type generic and return back to the `callingmethod`.

Comment: so... `public List<T> CalledMethod<T>()`... what's the problem?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I want the `CalledMethod()` to identify whether the call is of Type `Person` or `Department` and then run a SQL Read command, store it in a generic type list and return the result. I know you will say now from where SQL came into picture. My goal is I'm trying to build a generic function will process the command and return the result in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your CalledClass should accept T as generic.

Both your Person and Department should have atleast and Interface in common (if you need to do things with those objects.)

```
public class CalledClass<T> where T : IAmAClassObject {

    public List<T> CalledMethod() {
         //create your objects and do something
         return objects.ToList();
    }
}
```

Another way of handling this is to make the CalledMethod handle the generic
    public class CalledClass {

```
    public List<T> CalledMethod<T>() {
         //create your objects and do something
         return objects.ToList();
    }
}
```

This way you should instantiate the CalledClass once in the CallingClass class, and just call the CallMethod giving the right T type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could benefit from entity framework. It has the method you need, it is called using `DbContext`, `DbSet<T>` and Linq-to-sql.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to do this is the following:

```
public class CalledClass<T>
{
    public List<T> CalledMethod()
    {
         return objects.ToList();
    }
}
```

But this will not allow you to modify the list entries, because there are of type `object`.

Tour example shows that your objects are quite similar, so i would suggest extracting a common interface:

1. Remove the prefix `Person` and `Department` this information is already given with the class
2. Then moving those properties in an interface

This will leave you with the following hierarchy

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Name {set;get;}
    string Id {set;get;}
}

public class Person : IEntity 
{   
    string Name {set;get;}
    string Id {set;get;}
    string Address {set;get;}
}

public class Department : IEntity 
{   
    string Name {set;get;}
    string Id {set;get;}
    string Section {set;get;}
}
```

You can now add a constraint that your generic function only takes a child of `IEntity`

```
public class CalledClass<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public List<TEntity> CalledMethod()
    {
         // You can access Name and Id here
         foreach(var entity in entities) // i know the code is not useful ;) 
             entity.Id = "Unique ID";    // only for demonstration purposes
             entity.Name = "Random Name";
         }

         return entities.ToList();
    }
}
```